# Insert text from an textarea inton cloned textarea

Tags: jquery

If you click at an textarea, it appears box to write some text.

This text will be the text from the current textarea.

I added a button to clone the last textarea, and i want to do the same with the cloned textareas.

When someone click at a cloned textarea, it should write in the current textarea, but its not doing that, it only writes at the first.

Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2H2Hr/1/

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="descBox">
<br>
<span>Offer description</span><br><br>
<textarea id="txtareavalue"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Save" class="save">
<input type="button" value="Close" class="close">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.descBox
{
   display:none;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    position: fixed;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".clone").click(function(){
    $(".txtarea:first").clone(true).appendTo(".test");
   $(".txtarea:last").val('');
   $('#txtareavalue').val('');
  });

    $(".txtarea").click(function(){
    $(".descBox").toggle();
  });

      $(".save").click(function(){
    $(".descBox").toggle();
    $('.txtarea').text($('#txtareavalue').val());
  });

});
```

Comment: I don't really get what you want. If I type something in the first box and press 'clone' it clones an empty box and opens a save/cancel box where you can also place some text.. I don't understand the behaviour.. why do you even have this box?

Comment: I have a form with multiple input boxes and one textarea, the problem is that, i dont have too many space on my web page to put a big textarea, so i'm trying to make a different thing, i want to click at a small textarea, and expand this textarea on click. The problem is that i'm cloning my form, and i want to do that to the cloned forms.

Comment: Resuming, i want to show a box(with a textarea inside) when i click at the textarea, and write some text in there, and the text written in there will be the text from the click textarea.

Comment: and if you click on clone do you want to clone the first box all the time or the last changed box?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xuB44/2/ here you go. if you want to clone the last edited box instead of the first one all the time you can simply use lastchanged as a selector. you have to check if lastchanged is empty and if it is you have to use the first box (only on the first clone..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it is class selector on clicked item store it's reference in a variable and then use like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current;    // <----------
  $(".clone").click(function(){
    $(".txtarea:first").clone(true).appendTo(".test");
   $(".txtarea:last").val('');
   $('#txtareavalue').val('');
  });

    $(".txtarea").click(function(){
     current= $(this); //<-----------
    $(".descBox").toggle();
  });

      $(".save").click(function(){
    $(".descBox").toggle();

    $(current).val($('#txtareavalue').val()); //<------------
  });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/2H2Hr/8/)